# Magento 2 - Price filters and catalog price rules

Tags: magento2, price, filter, catalog-price-rules

How to make Magento 2 price filter to take into account prices with applied catalog price rules? Right now price filter ignores catalog price rules and work on prices without catalog price rules applied misleading the customer. Therefore catalog price rules feature is useless.